# How to do a "rolling" Multiplication starting with a fixed value

Tags: r

I am trying to multiply my monthly portfolio returns starting with an imaginary investment in t=1 of 100. So that in each month the new return is multiplied with the product of last month.

The orginal data basically looks like this:

```
    data <- data.table(RET=c("Jan","Feb","Mar"), Date=c(0.12,0.07,0.09))
    
RET Date
    1: Jan 0.12
    2: Feb 0.07
    3: Mar 0.09
```

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
data2 <- data.table(RET=c("Jan","Feb","Mar"), Date=c(0.12,0.07,0.09), Absolute=c(112,119.84, 130.6256))

 RET Date Absolute
1: Jan 0.12 112.0000
2: Feb 0.07 119.8400
3: Mar 0.09 130.6256
```

My limited r skills are unfortunately not enough to solve this basic problem i could have easily implemented in excel.. Maybe some of you can help me with a quick fix :)

Cheers, Frederik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
data[, Absolute := 100*cumprod(1+Date)]
#       RET  Date Absolute
#    <char> <num>    <num>
# 1:    Jan  0.12 112.0000
# 2:    Feb  0.07 119.8400
# 3:    Mar  0.09 130.6256
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base R with

```
data$Absolute <-  100*cumprod(1+data$Date)
```